# Saving a file in pyqt with inputs from code

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

```
input_example = QInputDialog.getText(self, "", "Please type your name here:") # this allows the users to enter their name

myfile = open(str(input_example) + ".txt","w") #this creates a new file with what the user has entered as the name of the file

myfile.write("Here is their score: " + str(self.points_Q11_L1) + "\n")  # this prints their score

myfile.close()
```

The code above asks for the users name and when they click ok, it creates the file, and titles the file like `("Example Name", True)`

Is there a way to remove the true so that it doesn't show ?

Comment: @TZHX Sorry but how would I examine this? (I am very new to coding so I am just learning, sorry!)

Comment: @TZHX if I type in my name and get it to print what was said, it comes back with this: ('Piers', True)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `input_example[0]` in the place where you're creating the file to only select the string result.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot for this :)